# How to determine if EMC PowerPath is installed on an ESX host using PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli, esx

TL;DR How can I use PowerCLI to determine if EMC PowerPath is installed on an ESX host?

I am attempting to write a script that will perform a host-masking operation when moving a LUN from one storage group to another. This is to accommodate the All Paths Down error that can occur due to a race condition in ESX 4.1. The steps are described in VMWare KB 1015084 and 1009449. These steps are written for use from the service console. I want to avoid scripting SSH activity and instead do the entire thing in Powershell/PowerCLI.

In our environment, we are using EMC PowerPath on most - but not all - of our hosts. This LUN masking only needs to be performed on hosts where PowerPath is installed, so I am attempting to test each host to determine this.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to determine how to do this with PowerCLI. If connected to the ESX service console, the command `esxcfg-mpath --list-plugins` will show if PowerPath is installed. In the vCenter GUI, it can be determined by:

`Select Host -> Configuration -> Storage Adapters -> Select Adapter -> View Devices -> Examine "Owner" column`

Using `get-scsilun` in PowerCLI returns an object that contains all this information **except** this Owner column.

I am stumped. I had hoped that a `get-esxcli` object would have some kind of equivalent methods, maybe in `satp` or `nmp`, but so far I can't find anything.

Comment: You might also want to ping the PowerCLI community forums: http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/server/vsphere/automationtools/powercli?view=discussions

Comment: Someone over at that forum got me on the right trail. The answer is:

`$esxcli.corestorage.plugin.list()`

Comment: Luc Dekens :-) Check out his blog: http://www.lucd.info/tag/powercli/

Comment: BTW - You should be able to answer your own question.

Comment: I'm too new to do that for another 5 hours. I'll be sure to do it then. And thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I'll answer my own question:

The answer is: `$esxcli.corestorage.plugin.list()` will return a list of plugins installed on the host.

Answer (score 0):

To get this information from PowerCLI 6.5 you can use the following:

```
(Get-ESXCLI -VMHost <host>).Storage.Core.Plugin.List()
```